# Is there a concurrency issue in this saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

So I have a saga like so

```
function* watchSelectThing() {
  let currentThing = yield select(getSelectedThing);
  while (true) {
    yield take(types.SELECT_THING);
    const nextSelectedThing = yield select(getSelectedThing);
    if (currentThing !== nextSelectedThing) {
      currentThing = nextSelectedThing;
      yield put(actions.updateSomeOtherThing({}));
      yield put(actions.fetchOtherStuff());
    }
  }
}
```

I have been told that there is a possibility that this saga could miss taking a `SELECT_THING` action because the select and puts are blocking the take. Like say, if a `SELECT_THING` action is fired while between the 2 puts. I suppose that seems reasonable.

If so, is there some way of forking (or doing something else) while still being able to retain the necessary state of `currentThing` so that it can be compared against the `nextSelectedThing`? My brain isn't seeing it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`take` waits for the next action to happen and does not have a buffer of past actions. To solve this you can use `takeLatest`.

```
let currentThing

function* saga() {
  currentThing = yield select(getSelectedThing);
  yield takeLatest(types.SELECT_THING, selectThingFlow)
}

function* selectThingFlow() {
  const nextSelectedThing = yield select(getSelectedThing);

  if (currentThing !== nextSelectedThing) {
    currentThing = nextSelectedThing;
    yield put(actions.updateSomeOtherThing({}));
    yield put(actions.fetchOtherStuff());
  }
}
```

The difference between `takeLatest` and `takeEvery` is in how `redux-saga` continues or cancels the executed flow. With `takeLatest` as soon a `SELECT_THING` action is fired, the `selectThingFlow` is canceled. So wherever the flow was (for example `updateSomeOtherThing`) the next action `fetchOtherStuff` would not be called anymore, but the flow will restart with `getSelectedThing`.

`takeEvery` however would also start another `selectThingFlow` starting with `getSelectedThing` but would not cancel the execution of the previous flow.

Comment: I had been thinking about that. But I wonder if that `yield select(getSelectedThing)` would cause the same issue.

Comment: Yes you are right. I changed the answer accordingly. Hope this helps!